# How much faster is sending 16 bit vs 32 bit over BLE?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project where I am sending information over BLE from a phone to a Raspberry Pi Zero. I can fit all the information I need into 16 bit messages, however, down the line I may need more bits, though I probably won’t. Would I be better off sending only 16 bit packets than 32 bit? Is it that much faster to send and parse 16 bits for a RPi Zero over BLE? I am only entertaining the idea of 32 bits because if I do need more information in the future, updating the code would be much easier.

The packets contain position data of the phone and will be send every .1 of a second. I am using Bleno on the Pi to receive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, those two extra bytes won't kill your energy budget. It's wise to keep reserved space for future use. It enables backwards compatibility and ease of future development. 
There's not really any difference in the length of the on-air packet transmission due to the big overhead of BLE, and you won't experience any difference due to the nature of connection intervals. We're talking 16bits/(10^6) = 16uS in 1mbps mode and 8uS in 2mbps mode.

Comment: Okay very interesting, thank you. In that case, how many bits can I send until I see a drop in performance?

Comment: That depends on packet length, transmission power, antenna characteristics, RF interference, and receiver sensitivity. These variables are very hard to simulate and you should set up test contitions for your use case and analyze the results. In general shorter packets are less prone to interference, but has more overhead per bytes of payload transferred. In the case of 2 bytes Vs 4 bytes there is almost no difference. You will not experience such issues untill you reach 60-240 bytes of payload.